# is it possible to convert an array of float to a string without an intermediary byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, copy

I need to send float arrays as strings. In the context of the app, we need the best performance possible.

From my reading on SO, the fast solutions all imply  converting the float array to a byte array first, then use either base64 or getBytes/getString with the cp1852 encoding.

So it is possible to avoid the intermediary byte array in c# ?

(of course, I would like to have the opposite conversion just as fast)

Comment: is there a reason you can't just call ToString on the Float? ie var str = floats.select(f=>f.ToString())

Comment: @MikeT OP needs a `string`. That will give `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: how do you want to convert float array into string. give example.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ah so he wants a single string not an array of string

Comment: So he wants to convert the internal binary representation of the float array to a string, rather than converting the float values themselves to strings? In other words, he wants to convert a byte array to a string.

Comment: Could you provide an example of data you have and what result you expect? For example, what should the result be if you have `float[] array = new float[] { 0.1f, 2.3f, 3.141f };`?

Comment: _"So it is possible to avoid the intermediary byte array in c# ?"_    Whats the problem with the intermediary byte array?   time? memory management? Why do you want to eliminate it?

Comment: _I need to send float arrays_ Where to?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen : I need perf,  mostly speed.  I added this aspect in the description.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, you're right.

Comment: If performance is the main goal then you need to keep everything at as low a level as possible as the more levels of abstraction you pile on top the more processing is involved, as such converting the float to a bytes is about as low level as you can get and any other solution while looking prettier will be less efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use it:

```
string resultString = string.Join(",", floatArray);
```

Comment: How'll you get back a float[]? Isn't that involve manual parsing

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Who wants to get a `float[]` back?

Comment: @Corak From question I assume it's another application. My point is he can just serizalize (xml,json, binary or whatever) the array and send instead of doing manual string manipulations.

Comment: My solution for back conversion is: 
            floatArray = resultString.Split(',').Select(x => float.Parse(x, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)).ToArray();

Comment: For that to work, you should have used `InvariantCulture` when converting the float array to string. If decimal separator is `,` then your answer won't work as expected.

Comment: That's a good point as certain cultures use , as a decimal point

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to convert it into a readable string representation? In this case you don't need to convert it into a byte array.

```
public static string ToDecimalValuesString(this float[] items, string separator = ", ")
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
    {
        result.Append(items[i].ToString("R", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
        if (i < items.Length - 1)
            result.Append(separator);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: With LINQ the method body boils down to: `return string.Join(separator, items.Select(item => item.ToString("R", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)));`